# Can I be sued by a hotel in Germany

Tags: germany, covid-19

I signed a non-refundable contract for a group stay at the Westin Grand Berlin for May 8, 2020. The group had to cancel the trip due to COVID-19 pandemic. The hotel sent me an invoice for the balance and threaten to forward it to their legal department if it's not paid immediately. Germany closed their boarders and does not allow tourists into the country. Can they sue me for the payment?

Comment: If the group and not the hotel cancelled, this seems like a pretty clear-cut case: for a non-refundable contract you have to pay even when you cancel. This would be entirely different if the hotel had cancelled your stay.

Comment: You need a real lawyer. There are so many details which might matter, from the fine print in your contract to the place of jurisdiction.

Comment: I'd think if you bring in the "German border lockdown" as a State Imposed cause, then that can be blamed instead of you or the hotel. What may be excruciating circumstances. Contact German authorities as well or lawyer who understands the above space.

Comment: You can't be held responsible for a contract you are legally prohibited from fulfilling. They can pound their fist on the table all they like, but judges are going to be swamped when this thing abates, and they'll give the swift boot to any case of this sort.  Court probably won't even let them file it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica “You can't be held responsible for a contract you are legally prohibited from fulfilling.” Is that a fact in Germany? Would that logic also apply to someone who is denied a visa or entry into the country?

Comment: I think that is not a correct assumption, @Harper-ReinstateMonica , as much as it seems to be common sense. The law will look at things like 'could/should the contract partner have known that you might not be able to legally fulfill it'. Many hotels have in their contracts clauses that push the responsibility to the customer, in the sense of 'if you are not showing up _for whatever reason_ you are still required to pay'. The question needs to be reviewed a lot more in detail, not just by common sense.

Comment: @Aganju Good point, I said that in a goofy way.  What I meant was "If your contract agrees for a party to break the law, that's unenforceable". No court is going to punish a non-actor for NOT breaking the law.  And following, "Without a quid pro quo, there is no contract", so if the action which is the crux of the contract is illegal, boom, no contract.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica as I understand it the quid pro quo requirement is a feature of contract law in common law systems, but not in others, so it may not be applicable to Germany. It seems that civil contract law often arrives at the same result by a different route, however.  I think the likelihood that there's something applicable in the relevant consumer protection law is probably pretty high. Tami Berkovits should also keep in mind that the company might even have known that they had no hope of prevailing and sent the letter in the hope that the customer wasn't as well informed.

Comment: Yeah, sending a letter like that as a bluff is basically zero risk for the hotel. Even if 1% of people pay, they cover the postage. And I expect more like a 20% hitrate.  Quid pro quo is so organic to the very idea of a contract that it would surprise me if any system omitted it.  It'd be like having a corporate entity without a liability shield, what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

The crucial point is if the **hotel** is able to fulfil the contract. This is decided on May, 3, as the new policies for Berlin are rolled out that day.

Chances are high tourism is still not allowed in Berlin on May, 8, so the hotel cannot fulfil. That's why they are eager to have their guests' money now. Because if a guest payed, the guest had to sue them to get her money back, and if the hotel goes bankrupt, the guest won't get a cent.

And that's why **I** personally would not pay a cent in the current situation. If against all odds tourism is going to be allowed on May, 8, I would pay as soon as I took notice of that, on May, 3. From now, that's still within the payment notice/reminder period. They could bill me a few Euro for late payment, not more.

Comment: The hotel welcomes the guests. That they cannot reach it is their problem.

Comment: @Greendrake: What you fail to understand is that tourism is prohibited in Germany at the moment. They can welcome their guests as much as they like, they aren't allowed to host them. And that policy most likely continues for the next months.

Comment: Not allowed to host? If I by whatever means walk in and ask for a room, will they refuse? You should provide reference.

Comment: *If I by whatever means walk in and ask for a room, will they refuse?* They **must** refuse. https://www.berlin.de/corona/massnahmen/verordnung/ §6(2) — no tourist vacancies

Comment: Well done. Upvoted. But this is weird actually. What do they do with tourists that are stuck in the country? Leave them on the street?

Comment: That for sure not. I'm inclined to think tourists who are stranded should contact their consulates to arrange their own transfer home, and if this is not possible at the moment, the consulate will arrange a permission with the German authorities (and funds, if neccessary) for their stay in that hotel they are in currently.